# Debugging from visual studio does not find file next to executable. When program ran manually, it does

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to test an SFML program and I have a problem when debugging it. I am loading two files that are located next to the executable; an image and a configuration file.
If I run the program from inside the output folder manually, it all runs ok.
If I try to run the program from inside Visual Studio (using the local windows debugger), my program cannot find the two specific files.

I even printed argv[0] to make sure it is the same file that the debugger tries to run.

Any ideas?

P.S. I have checked the output files 10 times now, it is the same file

Comment: Did you set the current working directly correctly in the debug configuration?

Comment: Apparently no... Did not even know this existed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bathsheba pointed out, one needs to set the working directory in Properties->Debugging->Working Directory

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.